# Which file format is this and how to open it?

Tags: dataset

Which file format is this and how to open it?

1435708910.94,state,{"CLOSE_TIME": 1435752000, "SERVICE_STATES": {"LED1": {"USED_MINS": 96.91667685111364, "FAIL_MINS": 0, "PAYG_CREDITS_USED": 0, "LAST_USE": [1435708747.965771, 9], "LAST_AVAIL": [1435708731.860505, true], "FREE_MINS": 374.18972703218475, "CHARGE": 96.91667685111364, "LVD_MINS": 0, "NODATA_MINS": 0}, "LED2": {"USED_MINS": 96.99929953018822, "FAIL_MINS": 0, "PAYG_CREDITS_USED": 0, "LAST_USE": [1435708728.138294, 0], "LAST_AVAIL": [1435708721.04487, true], "FREE_MINS": 141.17060283819833, "CHARGE": 96.99929953018822, "LVD_MINS": 0, "NODATA_MINS": 0}, "USB1": {"USED_MINS": 0, "FAIL_MINS": 0, "PAYG_CREDITS_USED": 0, "LAST_USE": [1435708713.425554, 0], "LAST_AVAIL": [1435708702.763062, true], "FREE_MINS": 0, "CHARGE": 0, "LVD_MINS": 0, "NODATA_MINS": 0}}, "OPEN_TIME": 1435665600, "PAYG_CREDITS_USED": 0, "KERNEL_VERSION": "4.0", "LED_QUOTA_USED": 193.9159763813019, "USB_QUOTA_USED": 0, "USB_QUOTA_END": 1435665621.729028, "KERNEL_AUTHOR": "CA", "LED_QUOTA_END": 1435686998.772021}

Comment: It's a .json file...A lot of software can open this file extension...

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `1435708910.94,state,` from the beginning, the rest is a JSON string. You can open the file in any text editor like Notepad, although a specialized JSON editor gives you more features like formatting it to be easier to read. You can try this [online JSON Editor](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_json_editor.htm).

Here is the formatted version:

```
{
    "CLOSE_TIME": 1435752000,
    "SERVICE_STATES": {
        "LED1": {
            "USED_MINS": 96.91667685111363,
            "FAIL_MINS": 0,
            "PAYG_CREDITS_USED": 0,
            "LAST_USE": [
                1435708747.965771,
                9
            ],
            "LAST_AVAIL": [
                1435708731.860505,
                true
            ],
            "FREE_MINS": 374.18972703218475,
            "CHARGE": 96.91667685111363,
            "LVD_MINS": 0,
            "NODATA_MINS": 0
        },
        "LED2": {
            "USED_MINS": 96.99929953018822,
            "FAIL_MINS": 0,
            "PAYG_CREDITS_USED": 0,
            "LAST_USE": [
                1435708728.138294,
                0
            ],
            "LAST_AVAIL": [
                1435708721.04487,
                true
            ],
            "FREE_MINS": 141.17060283819833,
            "CHARGE": 96.99929953018822,
            "LVD_MINS": 0,
            "NODATA_MINS": 0
        },
        "USB1": {
            "USED_MINS": 0,
            "FAIL_MINS": 0,
            "PAYG_CREDITS_USED": 0,
            "LAST_USE": [
                1435708713.425554,
                0
            ],
            "LAST_AVAIL": [
                1435708702.763062,
                true
            ],
            "FREE_MINS": 0,
            "CHARGE": 0,
            "LVD_MINS": 0,
            "NODATA_MINS": 0
        }
    },
    "OPEN_TIME": 1435665600,
    "PAYG_CREDITS_USED": 0,
    "KERNEL_VERSION": "4.0",
    "LED_QUOTA_USED": 193.9159763813019,
    "USB_QUOTA_USED": 0,
    "USB_QUOTA_END": 1435665621.729028,
    "KERNEL_AUTHOR": "CA",
    "LED_QUOTA_END": 1435686998.772021
}
```